# How to use vim for editor when running fc?

Tags: vim, fc

I have a machine for which when I run `fc` it opens in the `nano` editor.  How can I switch the editor to `vim` when I edit a command with `fc`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your shell follow the POSIX standard, [the `fc` command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/fc.html) will use the variable `FCEDIT` as the editor.

Setting `FCEDIT` in your shell's initialisation files will make the built-in `fc` command use the indicated editor in any new shell sessions:

```
FCEDIT=vim
```

You may also specify an editor with `fc -e vim`.

Comment: There is no need to export this. It is used by the shell internally only.

Comment: @schily Unless `fc` is an external command.

Comment: `fc` cannot be an external command as it works on internal data structures of the shell. It is a hack to do some primitive history editing using an external editor instead of implementing a real history editor in the shell. BTW: I implemented a prototype of an integrated history editor in 1982 and the first shell with fully integrated history editing under cursor control in 1984. The Korn Shell introduced `fc` in 1983 and a real history editor in 1986. Using `fc` today looks like an anachronism. I am used to have an integrated history editor in the shell since 34 years...

Comment: @schily When pondering how I would implement `fc` as an external command, I realise that you may well be correct. I use `fc` daily, but mostly through `alias r='fc -s'`, and only rarely to actually edit old commands.

Comment: The shell I used in 1984 is called `bsh` and has been written at H.Berthold AG. It is not a Bourne like shell but rather similar to `csh` but still closer to `sh` than csh. I never had the need for something like `fc` and I only implemented it in the Bourne Shell (`bosh`) , see http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/bosh.html because the author of the POSIX test suite claims that XSI support is needed for compliance unless  you like to write only a shell for an embedded system. `dash` identifies as such a shell. It has no editor and no multi byte support.

Answer (score 2):

Just add to your /etc/profile following line, then log out and in again to make changes take affect.

```
export EDITOR=vim
```

Comment: I use it with `bash`.

Comment: Ah, yes, `bash` seems to use `EDITOR` if `FCEDIT` is unset, but not in POSIX mode.

Answer (score 2):

On Debian and Ubuntu:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config editor
```